# split python dataframe in to equal numbers based on the unique values of a column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe `df` looks something like this:

```
id  value 
10  a
10  d
10  g
10  g
10  g
23  g
23  h
11  h
11  h
11  h
44  h
44  h
```

I want to split this dataframe into n different dataframes such that each dataframe has approx equal unique ids.

i was trying something like below:

```
ids =df.id.unique()
ids_in_split =np.array_split(ids,n)
```

this creates the splits of ids that should be there in each split of `df`. How do I split the original df using the `ids_in_split`?
any other more efficient way to do this is also welcome.

*Editing for the expected outcome:*

say i want to split the df into n =2 they should be like:

```
df1 =
id  value 
10  a
10  d
10  g
10  g
10  g
23  g
23  h

df2 = 
id  value 
11  h
11  h
11  h
44  h
44  h
```

In the above output both the split have all records of equal number of the unique iDs

Comment: So what's the expected outcome?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 23, 23, 11, 11, 11, 44, 44], 
    'value': ['a', 'd', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h']})
```

We group by 'id' and then unpack the grouped data frame into a tuple for each group. The second item of the tuple is a data frame.

```
>>> df1, df2, df3, df4 = df.groupby('id')

>>> df1[1]
   id value
0  10     a
1  10     d
2  10     g
3  10     g
4  10     g

>>> type(df1[1])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unclear the type of output you're searching for, here is a possible interpretation and result:

```
df
Out[11]: 
    id value
0   10     a
1   10     d
2   10     g
3   10     g
4   10     g
...

df.reset_index()
Out[12]: 
    index  id value
0       0  10     a
1       1  10     d
2       2  10     g
3       3  10     g
4       4  10     g
...

df['split'] = df.reset_index().groupby('id')['index'].rank()


df.sort_values('split')
Out[17]: 
    id value  split
0   10     a    1.0
5   23     g    1.0
7   11     h    1.0
10  44     h    1.0
1   10     d    2.0
6   23     h    2.0
8   11     h    2.0
11  44     h    2.0
2   10     g    3.0
9   11     h    3.0
3   10     g    4.0
4   10     g    5.0
```

Now you can groupby `split` column to get your dataframes.

Comment: edited to add the expected outcome. apologies for the confusion.